# Send ViewModel back to controller with POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, post, model-binding

For MVC4, What's the best-practice way to send a `ViewModel` used to populate a view back to a controller via `POST`?

Comment: As per my understanding, You should `Html.BeginForm`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849398/mvc-3-form-post-and-persisting-model-data

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-helpers,-forms-and-validation#Exercise3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets assume you want a login form with this view model:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Using this view model in a view is straight-forward, just send a new instance of `LoginModel` to the view:

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    var model = new LoginModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

Now we can create the `Login.cshtml` view:

```
@model App.Models.LoginModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)

    @Html.CheckboxFor(model => model.RememberMe)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RememberMe)

    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
}
```

Now we have to create an action in the controller which handles the post of this form. We can do that like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Authenticate the user with information in LoginModel.
    }

    // Something went wrong, redisplay view with the model.
    return View(model);
}
```

The `HttpPost` attribute will ensure that the controller action only can be reached via a post request.

MVC will use its magic and binds all the properties from the view back to a `LoginModel` instance populated with the values from the post.

Comment: I wish you had more wrong than just RemberMe so an edit would fly~

Comment: There's a big difference between a "View Model" and "Domain Model". What you demonstrated was sending a "Domain Model" from/ to controller.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to have your `Post controller` accept the `ViewModel` as its parameter then map its properties to your domain model.

```
public class Model
{
     public DateTime Birthday {get;set;}
}

public class ViewModel
{
     public string Month {get;set;}
     public string Day {get;set;}
     public string Year {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    string birthday = viewModel.Month + "/" + viewModel.day + "/" + viewModel.year;

    Model model = new Model { Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(birthday) } ;
    // save 
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Well I am asking from the _View_ how can I easily post back a Model?

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing the code that would actually invoke the given controller, assumed we have the view model available in the front end part of the code.